# Can we create this a Rebuild letters and offset text animation in Blender?

Tags: text-object

Can we offset text animation with another (same) text animation like in this video in 3D?

Can we "rebuild" the letters and offset the animation like in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_E9W2vsRbQ)?
(the text offset effect in 1:33)

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hello @Duarte Farrajota Ramos , thank you for your comment, I tried to give as much information as I could regarding the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several effects here and I guess there are many ways to do them, like shapekeys. For the letter that are stretching, you could hook the vertices of your letter to an empty in *Edit* mode with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > *Hook to New Object*:

[image]

It will create an empty at the vertices position:

[image]

Then simply animate the empty location:

[image]

Of course each letter can be a separate object so that you can make them move independently.

For the letters filling themselves I'm not sure there's any easy tool in Blender, curves tend to bend the shapes, but you can make the film transparent and use some masks that have the *(Shader) Holdout* node in order to reveal the letter shape, and same thing you can use hooks to reshape these masks:

[image]

Comment: Hello @moonboots thank you so much for your detailed reply to my question. There are some great ideas here, I didn't think about using hooks, I used shape keys for the stretching of the letters, but I didn't find a way to "rebuild" the letters as it appears on the video, as well as get that smooth offset animation, so please allow me a few tries to see how can I apply your technique  and then I will update here regarding your suggested ways to achieve this effect. Thank you again!

Comment: as I said, to rebuild the letters you could try the holdout mask (or another kind of mask), it's not very convenient but I don't think Blender comes with the good tools for this kind of motion design effects, maybe someone will have better ideas though

Comment: thank you for your comment, yeah I too wish blender had some more tools in order to achieve such effect, but as I wrote, your solution looks promising, I will make a few tries with the holdout shader, see what I can come up with, and see if I somehow can create another copy and offset this animation and will update you like I said, so thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks for solving this issue. I did managed to create masks more easily with your hooks method, and succeeding offset the animation of the letters. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: hey, nice to hear!